# Is possible to install nginx with push module on windows?

Tags: windows, nginx

i have an application that make use of nginx and the Nginx Http Push Module (http://pushmodule.slact.net/). Today i use it on linux, but i want to use it on windows. Is there a way or a a pre-compiled package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The Windows code is not open source and Nginx cannot link modules dynamically, as such you're limited to the binaries offered on nginx.org and the modules they include.

On a related note, Nginx on Windows is really sub-optimal and not very fast, you do not want to run it for anything other than development environment.

Update: This answer is no longer valid, the Windows source code has been released and nginx can also link against dynamically built libraries if the library supports it. The [performance issues still apply](https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html).

Comment: tks for the answer Martin!

Comment: Does this answer still hold in 2016?

Comment: @DonOmondi Nope. It should be possible now as it's possible to build windows version from source and nginx also supports dynamically linked modules.

It has not had any performance improvements, though.